# How to do a linear Regression with summaries of a certain dataset in R?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to create a **linear regression in R** in which I use the dataset `globalterrorismdb_0718dist` to have the number of attacks per year (between 2000 and 2017) on the y-axis and the years on the x-axis. I already created for each year it´s own variable (`a <- count(globalterrorism, iyear == 2000)`, ..., `r <- count(globalterrorism, iyear == 2017)`). `gf_point(country~iyear, data = globalterrorismdb_0718dist)` <- That was my first try.. I did it with `library(mosaic)`

Comment: Hi, add `dput(globalterrorismdb_0718dist)`

Comment: You can use `lm()` function that is in a base package (not external), `stats`. In case, try to evaluate if a linear regression is the correct tool for your task.

Comment: @s_t sadly the linear regression is a requirement.. I want to analyse how the number of attacks changes by time

Comment: `linearMod <- lm(country ~ iyear, data=globalterrorismdb_0718dist)` is the basic linear regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
library(dplyr) 
globalterrorismdb_0718dist %>% 
  count(iyear) %>% 
  ggplot(.,aes(x = iyear, y = n))+geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "loess")+
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Number of attacks")
```

[image]

UPDATE:

```
  globalterrorismdb_0718dist %>% 
   count(iyear) %>% 
   lm(data = . , iyear~n) %>% summary()

Call:
lm(formula = iyear ~ n, data = .)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-15.637  -9.578  -4.462  11.605  17.101 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 1.984e+03  2.227e+00 890.832  < 2e-16 ***
n           2.449e-03  4.111e-04   5.958 3.61e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.7 on 45 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4409,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4285 
F-statistic: 35.49 on 1 and 45 DF,  p-value: 3.61e-07
```

Comment: That works pretty well, but my requirement is to interpret the outcome of my linear regression.. any solutions for that?

Comment: do you need plot of coefficients from lm model?

Comment: you can replace `loess` to `lm`

Comment: For example the outcome should look like this:

Comment: **Call:
lm(formula = country ~ iyear, data = globalterrorismdb_0718dist)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-161.90  -63.44  -21.67   36.27  888.47 
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2424.45974   39.46845   61.43   <2e-16 ***
iyear         -1.14474    0.01971  -58.09   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Residual standard error: 111.4 on 181689 degrees of freedom
etc...